# Different return types from mySQL stored function

Tags: mysql, function

Is it possible to return different data-types from a function?

e.g. a function that will usually return an integer, but sometimes a string?

Comment: Return the most compatible datatype. Then use convertion, explicit or implicit/contextual, if needed.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. Not the end of the world.